# Lock or Semaphore in aiomultiprocess library Python

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I'm creating a process pool from aiomultiprocess library & I want to use Lock as specified in code. I'm not able to find the Lock in aiomultiprocess library so I tried multiprocess lib Lock, but it is throwing Exception.

```
import asyncio
import os

import aiomultiprocess
from multiprocessing import Lock
from functools import partial


async def print_val(x, lock):
    # Some CPU-bound computation done with some async logic. Now Load the data one at a time.
    async with lock:
        await asyncio.sleep(2)
        print(f"Loading {x}")
    return x

async def main(process_pool):
    lock = Lock()
    batches = list(range(20))
    async for response in process_pool.map(partial(print_val, lock=lock), batches):
        print(f"response got {response}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    aiomultiprocess.set_start_method('spawn')

    process_pool = aiomultiprocess.Pool(processes=3)
    asyncio.run(main(process_pool))
```

Anyone help me find Lock/Semaphore which can be used in aiomultiprocess process-pool.

Comment: A couple of observations: Locks in combination with pools are a bit tricky (search on SO to see some of the related questions/answers). Locks from `multiprocessing` are _not_ async, i.e. in combination with a pool you're running quickly into deadlocks (the moment the pool decides to place more than one worker into the same process). You can sidestep this problem by directly spawning `aiomultiprocess.Worker`s. But: I don't see any performance gain as long as you need to lock?